# How to correctly load Cordova and Angularjs hybrid app with remote scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

We have a single page hybrid app developed with `cordova 3.4.0` and `angularJS` via `Hybrid app plugin(CPT2.0)` in visual studio 2013.
This app has some embedded resources (jquery, angularjs, bootstrap and few propietary code), and needs to get some other remote resources (angularjs modules, css and more). 
Remote resources are stored in a CDN and bundled via asp.net bundling.

This choice was made because the prerequisite is making fast update of the app without delay of store validation and publishing, and because we have a responsive website that shares angular templates and resources with this app.

The app html mainpage has a `<head>` section that references embedded script and for the remote script we write in dom some script tags (using `.append`) , because the base url of remote resources is a parameter stored in a config file.

After remote script loading, app has to wait cordova event `deviceready` event and when this event is fired, app should finally bootstrap the main angular app.

This is a basic sample of what we are doing:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- embedded scripts-->
        <script type="text/javasript" src="scripts/jquery.js" />
        <script type="text/javasript" src="scripts/angular.js" />
        <script type="text/javasript" src="scripts/embeddedScript2.js" />
        <script type="text/javasript" src="cordova.js" />

        <!-- remote scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // path to cdn bundle loaded from a xml config
            var serverbundle = 'http://loadedfromconfig.com/cdn/myBundleMobile.js';
            // path to angularjs bundle shared with website and loaded from xml config
            var angularbundle = 'http://loadedfromconfig.com/myBundleMobile.js';
            // simplified append to head of remote scripts with path composition
            $("head").append("'<script type='text/javascript' src='"+serverbundle+"'/>");
            $("head").append("'<script type='text/javascript' src='"+angularbundle+"'/>");

            // cordova events binded onload
            var app = {
                initialize: function(){
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                },
                onDeviceReady: function(){
                    // manual bootstrapping of angularjs app, when all ready
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
                }
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='javascript: app.initialize()'>

        <!-- HTML and AngularJS directives -->
        <angular-directive />

    </body>
</html>
```

My question is: 
what is the correct way to synchronize remote resources loading, cordova `deviceready` and angular bootstrapping?

The design above works great, but sometimes remote scripts are not loaded or `deviceready` starts early and bootstraps angular app before all its modules are properly loaded.
I have also tried to better synchronize script loading and cordova but without success because some designs are not compatible with all the tree target platforms (ios, wp8 and android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any sample code on hand, but what I would do in this situation is to:

- Package an initial version of all files with the app. The user may be offline the first time the app is run, so wouldn't be able to load the scripts remotely.
- On app start, see if the device is online.
- If online, download new scripts from CDN using $.ajax, and save them to the file system using the cordova file API.
- Add the downloaded scripts to the document by injecting script tags into the page that point to the file system.
- If app is offline, use the previously downloaded version of the scripts.

Also, note that Apple frowns upon this kind of dynamic loading of app code. If they detect it during review, they may reject it.

---

Edit:

I just re-read your code and realized that you are adding your script elements to the head, then immediately initializing bootstrap.

The loading of scripts is async, so you need to wait until they are complete.
You may want to use a script loader like require.js or curl.js to load those remote scripts instead. They should provide some notification that they are completely loaded.

Comment: This app use remote services and require a connection. We altready check if device is offline with cordova onOffline event. If device is offline the user cant be able to make anything.

Comment: If device is offline the user cant be able to make anything. When deviceready event is fired we need to fast bootstrap angular application for prevent long loading times. If we wait deviceready for make scrip download the user show interface too late, specially if he have a slow connection. What we need is an async load of scripts and in the meantime a loading of cordova stuffs, but with a sort of check for angular cant start before all remote scripts are loaded..

Comment: Ok i've see the edit. That's the point, how we can recive a notification of all'scripts are loaded properly? With requirejs we cant be able to use asp.net bundling..

Comment: Update: after many try finally i have stored all scripts in local storage, after app first start i check the hash of all script and if is changed i make download and refresh of localstorage scripts.